# Can't pass color from vertex shader to fragment shader

Tags: opengl, sharpgl

I'm new to OpenGL and study it using SharpGL which is simple C# binding to OpenGL functions.I'm trying to use the simplest vertex and fragment shaders. When fragment shader generates output by itself, everything is fine, but when it tries to use data which came from vertex shader, there's only a black screen. Shaders are successfully compiled and linked to a program. No errors were returned by OpenGL. 
After tons of articles, examples and tutorials I still have no idea why it happens.
Here's vertex shader.

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 color;

out vec3 rgb;

void main()
{
    rgb = vec3(1.0, 0.5, 0.5);
    gl_Position = vec4(position,  1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330

in vec3 rgb;

out vec3 outColor;

void main()
{
    //outColor = rgb; // black display
    outColor = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.4); // works fine
}
```

Here's initialization code:

```
gl.GenVertexArrays(1, arrayBuffer);
gl.BindVertexArray(arrayBuffer[0]);

gl.GenBuffers(1, pointsBuffer);
gl.BindBuffer(OpenGL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pointsBuffer[0]);
gl.BufferData(OpenGL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangle, OpenGL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

gl.GenBuffers(1, colorsBuffer);
gl.BindBuffer(OpenGL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorsBuffer[0]);
gl.BufferData(OpenGL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colors, OpenGL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

And finally here's what's happend on every iteration:

```
gl.Clear(OpenGL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | OpenGL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

gl.UseProgram(program.Id);

gl.BindBuffer(OpenGL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pointsBuffer[0]);
gl.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, OpenGL.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

gl.BindBuffer(OpenGL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorsBuffer[0]);
gl.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);
gl.VertexAttribPointer(1, 3, OpenGL.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

gl.DrawArrays(OpenGL.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12);

gl.DisableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.DisableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

**UPD 1**. Here's the data passed to buffers.

```
private float[] triangle = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 
};

private float[] colors = {
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f
};
private uint[] arrayBuffer = new uint[1];
private uint[] pointsBuffer = new uint[1];
private uint[] colorsBuffer = new uint[1];
```

**UPD 2** Here's shaders compilation code

```
private uint CompileProgram(OpenGL gl, List<ShaderMetadata> shaders)
{
    var program = gl.CreateProgram();

    shaders.ForEach(shader => gl.AttachShader(program, CompileShader(gl, shader.Path, shader.Mode)));

    gl.LinkProgram(program);

    var status = ProgramErrorInfo(gl, program);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(status))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(status);
    }

    return program;
}

private uint CompileShader(OpenGL gl, string path, uint kind)
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            var program = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var id = gl.CreateShader(kind);
            gl.ShaderSource(id, program);
            gl.CompileShader(id);

            var status = ShaderErrorInfo(gl, id);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(status))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(status);
            }

            return id;
        }
    }
}

private string ShaderErrorInfo(OpenGL gl, uint shaderId)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(2048);
    gl.GetShaderInfoLog(shaderId, 2048, IntPtr.Zero, builder);
    return builder.ToString();
}

private string ProgramErrorInfo(OpenGL gl, uint programId)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(2048);
    gl.GetProgramInfoLog(programId, 2048, IntPtr.Zero, builder);
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

**UPD 3** And here's how compiler is invoked

```
var programId = CompileProgram(gl, new List<ShaderMetadata>
            {
                new ShaderMetadata(
                    @"vertex.shader",
                    OpenGL.GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
                new ShaderMetadata(
                    @"fragment.shader",
                    OpenGL.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
            });
```

Comment: I do not see your code to create the shader program.

Comment: @JojOatXGME Attached in UPD 2 and 3

Comment: Forgive my ignorance with C#, but how is an array large enough to hold a single unsigned integer supposed to store all of that vertex data? Each `float` component is the same size as a single integer.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Probably it's a bad naming issue. uint array stores not vertex data, it just keeps a reference to OpenGL buffer. The data itself is stored in float arrays (triangle, colors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was resolved by unmounting a shader program after drawing:

```
gl.DrawArrays(OpenGL.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12);
gl.UseProgram(0);
```

Anyway, if anyone has an explanation or a reference to doc or something, you are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `flat` to both the out and in of `rgb`.  This prevents an interpolation step and maps the vertex output directly to the fragment input.  While it may not give you the result you want with the triangle colouring, it will help you to isolate the issue.

Comment: He's passing a *constant value*; how could it be interpolated?

Comment: @NicolBolas you are right, I am probably off base on this one. I misremembered a similar issue I had when trying to pass integers from vertex to fragment shaders, for which `flat` is required.